# How to improve diagnostic table

Tags: database, oracle, testing, plsql

Our team just finished a big DB replication process and I'll be running maintenance on the system. Currently I have a table created using inline views that shows the count for all types objects and their status (VALID/INVALID). So for example the table shows the total count of valid and invalid objects for all the packages or jobs and triggers. My question is what else can I do to improve testing for the Database. I'm using TOAD as my DBMS if that matters.

Comment: I'm not understanding the question.  What does object status have to do with replication?  Other than during a code promotion, why would you have invalid objects in a production database?  What are you trying to test exactly?

Comment: agreed, you should not have invalid objects, except perhaps, materialized views which become invalid at the drop of a hat but are still usable.

Comment: Your'e correct. We shouldn't have invalid objects. The table acts as a daily check up. Basically, I come in to work, check the table and make sure their are no invalid objects. If there are than I need to trouble shoot the objects.

Comment: Toad has a tab in the schema browser for invalid objects.  If you have a lot of schema that gets unwieldy and a custom view would be easier

Answer (score 0):

> What else can I do to improve testing for the Database?

- have all developers log their errors to a central logging table
- have one package to store data that is widely used and rarely changed like the host name of the Active Directory server, mail server, instance names of development, QA and production.  (so you can do statements like if instance_name = Production then Do not run, raise an error)
- have a table or package that stores all custom error numbers
- have a naming convention and stick to it
- create a package that looks in the error logging table and emails a summary or digest to developers when errors are logged, extend it to notify you when a job has failed